# How to stop current thread if it fails and get new thread in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

```
Threads: 1000 

1. Validate username
2. Validate Password
If controller
    3. User Info
    4. Settings
    5. Payments
    etc...
    20. Logout
```

Now if Validate Password is failed then the subsequent run will be not run..  But still thread is counted.. Consider 800 is success and 200 login is failing still it shows Active 1000 Started: 1000.

I dont want the thread which is failed on validate password, How to stop the thread which is failed and instead getting new thread.. I want thread which runs all the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Action to be taken after a sampler error option in [thread group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), [image]

In your case if you wish to `stop thread` on error you can check stop thread option , but remember if you check stop thread it wont start any further iterations.

If you wish to stop thread and start a new iteration on error you can check `start next thread loop` option

For more information on thread groups follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/)

Comment: Does it create 1000 threads with all the steps to be run. will stop the thread that fails inbetween.. right?

Comment: Yes initially it creates 1000 threads and if you check stop thread option it will stop those threads that fails in between so the thread count decreases

Comment: If you want to maintain 1000 threads  then you can keep start next thread loop so that the if a thread fails it just stops the iteration and starts a fresh iteration

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: Rohit, Just a one more question, I dont want to stop the thread which is failing on If Controller..I wanted to stop only if it fails on validate username and password. But looks like that it will stop and create new thread even if it fails on If controller loop as well. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread group to stop thread if sampler fails. Check below option if it satisfies your requirement:-

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: will it continue the next iteration??